# Hyper Ledger Fabric CA Server Setup Error with IP SANS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup blockchain network with two organizations having two peers in each organization. I generated crypto material using fabric-ca-server-client command after setting up separate CAs for org1, org2 and orderer organizations. All peers and orderers are running in different containers in a single VM. Issue is about IP SANS.

```
# Register peer0 certificates now
fabric-ca-client register --caname ca.org1.example.com --csr.cn peer0.org1.example.com --csr.names 'O=org1,OU=peer,C=IN,ST=Telangana' --id.name peer0 --id.secret peer0pw --id.type peer --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer"' --tls.certfiles ${FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME}/ca/tls-ca-org1-example-com-cert.pem

# Enroll peer0 certificates now which stores crypto material for peer0 in msp folder
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://peer0:peer0pw@localhost:7060 --caname ca.org1.example.com --csr.cn peer0.org1.example.com --csr.names 'O=org1,OU=peer,C=IN,ST=Telangana' -M ${FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME}/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp --csr.hosts peer0.org1.example.com --tls.certfiles ${FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME}/ca/tls-ca-org1-example-com-cert.pem
```

I am getting below error while executing docker logs peer0.org1.example.com

```
2022-03-05 08:49:11.635 UTC [grpc] Warningf -> DEBU 04f grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:7051  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs". Reconnecting...
2022-03-05 08:49:11.636 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 052 Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2022-03-05 08:49:11.636 UTC [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 053 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc002ae4e40, {TRANSIENT_FAILURE connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"}
2022-03-05 08:49:11.636 UTC [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 054 Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2022-03-05 08:49:11.635 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 050 Server TLS handshake failed in 945.487µs with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:38460
2022-03-05 08:49:11.637 UTC [grpc] Warningf -> DEBU 055 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "127.0.0.1:38460": remote error: tls: bad certificate
```